# PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')

Tags: php, linux, email, pear

When i send mail using SMTP i am getting error like

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in ...

How can i debug this? I have installed PEAR module correctly. 
Installed pear list is

```
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.11  stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1   stable
HTML_Common      1.2.5   stable
HTML_Page2       0.6.3   beta
Mail             1.2.0   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

Need to install any other pear dependences?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to find Mail.php (`pear list-files Mail`) on your system and identify why it is not I  your include path. Be aware your include path may be different between cli and web.

Comment: Hi..thanks for the reply.when i try this (pear list-files Mail) php  /home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Mail.php and include_path is .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

Comment: need to change include path ?

Comment: Certainly looks that way, yes.

Comment: hi.. i had set include path like this set_include_path('.:/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear:/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear'); in top of the php page, But i am getting the same fatal error only.

Comment: also i tried this way require_once "/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Mail.php";

Comment: I've seen scenarios where you might need to add a colon to the end of that; so: set_include_path('.:/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear:/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pea‌​r:');

Comment: Old post I know - but is it pos to see how the Mail function is being used?

Answer (score 1):

Use terminal to check where Pear is installing `.php` files.
Use command `pear config-get php_dir` to get the right directory.
Use the [Pear Manual to verify you Pear configuration](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php) and for debug.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the Pear message.

You need to find the correct path to Mail.php.

If it is in the same folder then it will look like this:

```
require_once('Mail.php')
```

If not, then use absolute path. EG:

```
require_once('/var/www/Mail.php')
```

Or whatever the relative path is:

```
require_once('directory/Mail.php')
```

Comment: -1. Not sure what you mean by "ignore the pear message" - Mail.php is from a pear package. Requiring with an absolute path would probably just fail at the next pear include statement.

Comment: On a Linux system running PHP if you have a require_once() with a broken path, you generally get the pear reference in the error message. Fixing the path to the file generally resolves the problem without having to install other Pear modules or dependancies.

Comment: "The pear reference" do you mean the include path in the error message? If so: No kidding. `Mail             1.2.0   stable` Mail.php _is_ a pear module. See [the docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php) for example usage. Btw require is not a function (it doesn't need/shouldn't have parenthesis).